# I can't evaluate delayed and ordered expressions in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

In Javascript (Node), I should run several expressions in an order and in some delays. This doesn't work because all of them run immediately, together in a mixed order;

```js
var i = 0;

function run(){
  console.log(i++);
};

setTimeout(run, 500);
setTimeout(run, 500);
setTimeout(run, 500);
setTimeout(run, 500);
```

And this is not good:

```js
var i = 0;

function run(){
  console.log(i++);
};

setTimeout(run, 500);
setTimeout(run, 1000);
setTimeout(run, 1500);
setTimeout(run, 1600);
```

Because It should stop evaluating the next expression. My program flow will go somewhere else and the function will run for no reason.

I need some synchronous functions to run with delay and in my written order. I couldn't implement it.

I don't know If I screwed up the design. I just want to make an online game clicking bot. But this is something different. This web bot should act like a human and click things with a random delay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at Promises, and in special into [bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/getting-started.html). They have a delay method that will do exactly what you are after.

```
const Promise = require('bluebird');

Promise.resolve(1)
    .delay(500)
    .then((n) => {
        console.log(n);
        return ++n;
    })
    .delay(1000)
    .then(n => console.log(n));
```

Answer (score 0):

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uk0qw7t6/3/)

```
var i = 0;

function run (delay) {
  return function () {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      setTimeout(function () {
        console.log(i++);
        resolve();
      }, delay);
    });
  };
}

Promise.resolve()
  .then(run(500))
  .then(run(1000))
  .then(run(1500));
```